# hammerjs jquery pull down refresh knockout binding

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-animate, hammer.js

I am trying to write a knockout binding handler to do a pull to refresh functionality (similar to umpteen number of apps on ios). So, I used Hammer.js for touch gestures, jquery animation to animate the items in question and wrote a binding handler.

Here is the fiddle for the same. http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/Jy8Yg/38/

All works well and good when the drag and release is fast. But when I am dragging the div down slowly, the top gray refresh bar overlaps the bottom div. In other words, the animation of the gray refresh area seems to happen faster than the bottom div which is being dragged. I must be missing something trivial here. Another set of eyes will definitely help. See anything wrong? Can someone help me out?

```
 init: function(element, valueAccessor) {

    var $element = $(element), handler = valueAccessor(),
        $pullToRefresh = $('<div/>', {'class': 'pull-refresh-slide'}),
        $pullMessage = $('<div/>', {'class': 'pull-message'});

    $pullToRefresh.append($pullMessage);

    $element.before($pullToRefresh);
```

and here is the code inside the dragdown release handle.

```
var mTop = ev.gesture.deltaY,
    pTop = parseInt($pullToRefresh.css('top'));

    console.log('pTop: ' + pTop);
    console.log('mTop: ' + mTop);
    console.log('pTop + mTop : ' + (pTop + mTop));

    if(pTop + mTop > 0 ){
        pTop = 0;
        $pullMessage.addClass('release');
    }
    else
        pTop = pTop + mTop;


     if(mTop > parseInt($pullToRefresh.height()))
         mTop = parseInt($pullToRefresh.height());


     $element.animate({'margin-top': mTop },{duration: ev.gesture.deltaTime / 100, queue: false});
     $pullToRefresh.animate({'top': pTop},{duration: ev.gesture.deltaTime/100, queue: false});
```

The last two animate functions don't seem to happen in tandem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically solved this by adjusting the deltaTime for the pullToRefresh based on the animation of $element. So added a callback to animation complete on $element to animate $pullToRefresh.